# Aggregate Value Compiling Error in C with Array Struct

Tags: c, function, compilation

In a large project requiring a make file a compiling error of "aggregate value used where an integer was expected" at this line in our code:
`* balance = (size_t)a->data[indexUser];`

This is our function where the line is implemented to get the value balance stored in array a at the index of a certain user where array is a struct

```
int userBalanceGet(array *a, size_t indexUser, size_t * balance){
      if(!a || !balance || indexUser >= a->inUse) return -1;
      * balance = (size_t)a->data[indexUser];
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the data member of the array type is a struct or a union, which can't be cast to a `size_t`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We can’t help you more because there isn’t enough information to tell us how the variables are declared.